# Download counter for items separately but same for different languages

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make a counter for every "Book" download.

The first thing to notice is that some books have different language downloads.

What I want to achieve is that if a book has only 1 download counter it increases it and if it has different languages downloads, then all increases also in just 1 counter.

Counter is on the right:
[image]

I have managed to implement a button click counter with help from the nice people of this forum, this is the resulting code:

```
<?php

$counterFile = 'counter.txt' ;

// jQuery ajax request is sent here
if ( isset($_GET['increase']) )

{
    if ( ( $counter = @file_get_contents($counterFile) ) === false ) die('Error : file counter does not exist') ;
            file_put_contents($counterFile,++$counter) ;
            echo $counter ;
            return false ;
        }

        if ( ! $counter = @file_get_contents($counterFile) )
        {
            if ( ! $myfile = fopen($counterFile,'w') )
                die('Unable to create counter file !!') ;
            chmod($counterFile,0644);
            file_put_contents($counterFile,0) ;
        }

    ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).on('click','a#download',function(){
             jQuery('div#counter').html('Loading...') ;
             var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
                 method : 'get',
                 url : '/test.php', // Link to this page
                 data : { 'increase' : '1' }
             }) ;
             ajax.done(function(data){
                 jQuery('div#counter').html(data) ;
             }) ;
             ajax.fail(function(data){
                 alert('ajax fail : url of ajax request is not reachable') ;
             }) ;
         }) ;
     </script>
<div id="counter"><?php echo $counter ; ?></div>
<a href="<?php echo get_field("pdf"); ?>" id="download" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Download btn</a>
```

The problem with this solution is that it is counting the same for all books, it doesn't separate each book download.

I found this tutorial: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/02/php-mysql-download-counter/demo.php
But the problem I see is that it counts every file download, so if I apply it to my site, then the books that has different language will be counted in different numbers.

How can I make it work the way I'm looking for? Like I said, if a book has only 1 download counter it increases it and if it has different languages downloads, then all increases also in just 1 counter.

Comment: How do you generate the pages for books? Are they dynamically created from database or are they hard-coded each one separately in pure html? If you are using framework, which one?

Comment: Oh, I see, you are using wordpress. Not my thing. I suggest you added wordpress tag and information, as it may help getting help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is definitely with a database, but in case you want to do this with a file the below should do the trick.

The class, `DownloadCount`, handles all the counter operations, and stores the counter information in a JSON file, indexed by book filename:

- `get()` returns the download count for the specified book.
- `update()` increments the download count for the specified book and returns the new download count.
- `save()` writes any counter changes to the file.

*Note that this is not robust as it's posssible for simultaneous requests to intefere with each other (this is why a database is preferred).*

```
<?php

class DownloadCount
{
    protected $_file;
    protected $_counters;

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $this->_file = $file;
            $this->_counters = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
            if (empty($this->_counters)) $this->_counters = [];
        } else {
            die('Error : file counter does not exist');
        }
    }

    public function get($book)
    {
        $book = basename($book);

        return (array_key_exists($book, $this->_counters)
            ? $this->_counters[$book]
            : 0);
    }

    public function update($book)
    {
        $book = basename($book);

        if (array_key_exists($book, $this->_counters)) {
            $this->_counters[$book]++;
        } else {
            $this->_counters[$book] = 1;
        }

        return $this->_counters[$book];
    }

    public function save()
    {
        file_put_contents($this->_file, json_encode($this->_counters), LOCK_EX);
    }
}

$count = new DownloadCount('./counter.json');

if (!empty($_GET['increase'])) {
    // this is the ajax response of the incremented count.
    echo $count->update($_GET['increase']);
    $count->save();
    exit;
} else {
    $pdf = get_field('pdf');
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on('click', 'a#download', function()
        {
            jQuery('div#counter').html('Loading...');
            console.log(this.href);
            var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
                method : 'get',
                url : '/test.php', // Link to this page
                cache: false,
                data : { 'increase' : this.href }
            });
            ajax.done(function(data)
            {
                jQuery('div#counter').html(data);
            });
            ajax.fail(function(data)
            {
                alert('ajax fail : url of ajax request is not reachable');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="counter"><?php echo $count->get($pdf); ?></div>
    <a href="<?php echo $pdf ?>" id="download" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Download btn</a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I've written it above (and as I interpreted your example). You'd need to modify it to make it work for your specific requirement within wordpress. But there's no reason you can't break it up and use `include()` or another method on parts of it.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about making it work within wordpress. If it's just to put it all in a page I can make its easy, the problem is that right now it's giving me error on this line: `if (empty($this->_counters)) $this->_counters = []; ` I don't know if its a syntax thing error

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /usr/home/Site/web/wp-content/themes/site_theme/single-books.php on line 47`

Comment: Ah, I guess you're using a lower PHP version than 5.4, where the short array syntax was introduced.  Change `[]` to `array()`.

Comment: That's a part of your code I copied - if the `counter.json` file doesn't exist in the same folder it'll show that error. Either create the file manually or remove the line `die('Error : file counter does not exist');`

Comment: Ok, no more errors now :) But if I click on "Download btn" file is downloaded but the counter dissapears. Also if I reload it stays at `0`. Should I put any code on the `test.php` file? Should I put any code on the `counter.json` file?

Comment: The ajax response is blank - it should contain just the number returned by `update()`. Check the counter.json file to see if anything was added.

Comment: the `counter.json` is blank. Also the `test.php`

Comment: Is the php file where you've put the code called `test.php`? If not you need to change the `url` param of the ajax method to match the correct filename.

Comment: Ok, try just with a blank url - `url: ''` - this will submit to the same page that was loaded.

Comment: Ok, I get there the `url` with `get_permalink`. Let me try some things and tell you how it is going

Comment: Do you see the post getting doubled and spam content there? this is so strange :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65176/discussion-between-codek-and-timclutton).

Answer (score 1):

You have only one file, containing only one number to count all books. Obviously this goes wrong since that single file is supposed to do it for every book.

As far as I know the best way to keep download counts is saving them in a database table with book_ID and download_count. then when you need to update you do `UPDATE downloadcounters SET download_count = download_count + 1 WHERE book_ID = <id of book>`. getting the download count is just as easy with `SELECT download_count FROM downloadcounters WHERE book_ID = <id of book>`

If you need to do it with a file for some reason I'd advice you to do it in a CSV file where you keep the book id and count. And let php read through the file line by line until you found the ID of your current book. Then edit or read its value

Comment: Ok, so I need to create a database. But when adding a new book how it is going to be saved automatically? I need to save it in the database manually?

Comment: You could add an extra query to the creation and deletion of books to create an entry in the database. you could also say that non existing rows are count 0 per default and if the counter goes up and the row doesn't exist create it. Or create it when getting count has 0 results. But that's entirely up to you.

Comment: @codek Also, if this solves your question, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: No, I haven't found how to do it with your suggestion, this is not solving my question, sorry